# Verify that an expression can be evaluated

Tags: functions, symbols

Suppose I have a string:

```
str="sin(x)*25+exp(1.5*y)"
```

I want to be able to evaluate it in *Mathematica*. I can do this, of course:

```
expr=ToExpression[str,TraditionalForm]
```

> `E^(1.5 y) + 25 Sin[x]`

Now I can use this expression to construct a function or simply evaluate it. The problem is that some of the functions in the string could be custom functions that may or may not be defined in *Mathematica* already, such as

```
str2="sin(x)*25+exp(1.5*y)+f(x*y)"
expr2 = ToExpression[str2, TraditionalForm]
```

> `E^(1.5 y) + f[x y] + 25 Sin[x]`

I want to verify that all the functions in the `expr2` are defined, in other words, the expression can be evaluated.

I can do:

```
Cases[expr2, x_[__] :> x, Infinity] // Union
```

> `{f, Power, Sin, Times}`

But how to verify that all of the functions have been defined already? Are the other ways to approach the problem?

Comment: I think you can look at the `DownValues` of the symbol. If your symbol has associated transformation (i.e. already been defined) then it will not be empty, else you'll get empty list.

Comment: @Nasser Good idea, but the problem is that `DownValues` of all built-in functions are empty, and I don't know how to distinguish between built-in and custom functions.

Comment: That is correct, but may be check the context also. `Context[Power]` and `Context[Sin]` etc.. all give `System`. So one way might be to check the context first, and for those not in `System` only then look if they have DownValues?

Comment: @Nasser Great suggestion! Thank you. This deserves to be an answer.

Comment: What if `f` has definitions but not for given argument pattern? e.g. `f[x_]:=x`.

Comment: @Kuba This is potentially a problem, but as a first approximation I think I can assume that there is either no function defined at all or the correct function exists if it is defined. It's a right question though and it might probably require further analysis of `DownValues`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In:

```
ClearAll[f, xs, UndefinedQ]
UndefinedQ[x_] := Definition[x] // ToString // "Null" == # &
xs = {f, Power, Sin, Times};
xs // Select[UndefinedQ]
```

Out:

```
{f}
```